# ActiveRecord labels usando I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, i18n

Tenho o seguinte código:

**pt-BR.yml**

```
activerecord:
  attributes:
    city:
      codigo_municipio: "Código do município"
```

**View**

```
= label(:city, :codigo_municipio)
```

**Resultado esperado:**

```
# => <label for="cities_codigo_municipio">Código do municipio</label>
```

**Resultado obtido:**

```
# => <label for="cities_codigo_municipio">Codigo municipio</label>
```

Segundo a **[documentação](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-label)** está tudo correto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método **label** utiliza somente a tradução do helper:

```
helpers:
  label:
    city:
      codigo_municipio: "Código do município"
```

Se já tenho a tradução no **activerecord.attributes** não é conveniente duplicar o código para efetuar a tradução, então para resolver este problema, basta utilizar o **human_attribute_name**, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
= City.human_attribute_name(:codigo_municipio)
```

Deste modo o rails passa a utilizar o **activerecord.attributes** em vez de **helpers.label**